# Attempting to rewrite to a friendlier URL

Tags: apache

For the last few hours I have been trying to have my URLs rewrite as follows:

Example:

http://www.practiceenglish.ca/podcast/index.php?name=2013-06-14_01-Practice-English.mp3

to

podcast/2013-06-14_01-Practice-English.mp3/podcast/2013-06-14_01-Practice-English.mp3/

No Luck... Latest attempt:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /podcast/
RewriteRule ^name/([^/]+)/?$  index.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

Thanks
Jillian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you meant it the other way round and that the original URL contains the podcast name once:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^podcast/(.*)$  /podcast/index.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

That translates any incoming URLs from `/podcast/2013-06-14_01-Practice-English.mp3` to `/podcast/index.php?name=2013-06-14_01-Practice-English.mp3` (tested @ http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

As you seem to be a new SO user, please take a look at the FAQ/help and at this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: Sorry, I wish my final output to be /podcast/2013-06-14_01-Practice-English.mp3/

Comment: @user2197774 With a trailing slash? That doesn't make sense imho, but ''^podcast/(.*)/$'' should do that.